# how can I make getaddrinfo return 'sctp' protocol?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, getaddrinfo, sctp

```
struct addrinfo hint, *result;
int res, sfd;

memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hint.ai_family   = AF_INET;
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

res = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hint, &result);
```

I think `getaddrinfo` should return two addrinfo when using 'SOCK_STREAM'. One protocol is `tcp`, the other protocol is `sctp`. However, `getaddrinfo` only return `tcp` protocol. I don't know why ?

I use ubuntu 14.04, linux kernel 3.19.0 and install `sctp` protocol by typing: `apt-get install libsctp-dev`

Comment: SCTP is using SOCK_SEQPACKET not SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: sctp_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP); url: http://www.openss7.org/man2html?sctp(7)

Comment: So do you have CONFIG_SCTP_TCP_COMPATIBLE set in your kernel configuration which according to this man page is required to have SOCK_STREAM available?